# How many of the n! terms in the expansion of a determinant of order n remain, if all the elements of the main diagonal are set to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

> How many of the $n!$ terms in the expansion of a determinant of order
> $n$ remain, if all the elements of the main diagonal are set to zero ?

Here is an argument

In the expansion of a determinant, each term is a product of $n$ elements, one from each row and column of the determinant. If we set all the elements on the main diagonal to zero, then for each term in the expansion, we cannot choose an element from the main diagonal. Therefore, we have $n-1$ choices for the first element in each term, $n-2$ choices for the second element, and so on, down to $1$ choice for the last element.

Thus, the number of terms in the expanded determinant with all the elements on the main diagonal set to zero is $(n-1)!$.

To see why this is true, note that there are $n$ choices for the first element in each term, but we cannot choose an element from the main diagonal, so there are only $n-1$ choices. After we choose the first element, there are $n-1$ choices for the second element (since we cannot choose an element from the first column), then $n-2$ choices for the third element (since we cannot choose an element from the first or second column), and so on, down to $1$ choice for the last element (since we cannot choose an element from any of the previous columns).

Therefore, the total number of terms in the expanded determinant with all the elements on the main diagonal set to zero is the product of $(n-1)$, $(n-2)$, ..., $1$, which is $(n-1)!$.

Please cheak this...or you can give another solution...

Comment: That's equal to the derangement problem, and the answer is approimately $n!/e.$

Comment: There are either $n-1$ elements for the second, or $n-2.$ Depending on whether the first row was $(1,2)$ or some other element. It is much more complicated than this.

Comment: When $n=4$ you get $6$ permutations of order $4$ and $3$ permutations of order $2.$

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Indeed, a bigger point here is: you could check your own solution on small numbers and see if it breaks. Here it breaks for $n=4$ ($9$ solutions instead of $6$) and by looking at why there are additional solutions you can see where you made a mistake in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

To each term $a_{1j_1} \cdots a_{nj_n}$ of the determinant expansion we can associate the permutation $$\pmatrix{1 \cdots n\\j_1 \cdots j_n} ,$$ and by definition the term is $0$ iff $j = j_i$ for some $i$, that is, if the permutation has a fixed point. So, the number of terms that survive is just the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$ objects, sometimes called the **subfactorial** of $n$ and denoted $!n$.

It can be expressed by $$n! \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} ,$$ which coincides for $n > 0$ with $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{e} \right\rceil$, where $\lfloor a \rceil$ denotes the integer closest to $a \in \Bbb R$. The counts for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots$ are, respectively, $0, 1, 2, 9, 44, \ldots$; see OEIS [A000166](https://oeis.org/A000166).